# Ajax 500 internal server error in laravel 7,

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csrf

I Already put the token in the data to be send but the error still 500 internal server error

in the web.php

```
Route::post('/Achievement', 'AchievementController@store');
url /Achievement   go to AchievementController and run function store
```

in the AchievementController

```
public function store(Request $req){
        $idPembicara= Pembicara::where('idUser','like',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $data = Penghargaan::create([
            'idPembicara'=>$idPembicara->id,
            'tahun' => $req['tahunRow1'],
            'lokasi' => $req['lokasiRow1'],
            
            
            
        ]);
        return $data;
    }
```

app.blade.php

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

achievement.blade.php

```
<form id="updateAchievement">
        {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tahunRow1" name="tahunRow1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lokasiRow1" name="lokasiRow1">
<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
    </form>

<script type="application/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#updateAchievement").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      var mData = {
        'lokasiRow1': $('input[name=lokasiRow1]').val(),
        'tahunRow1': $('input[name=tahunRow1]').val(),

        _token: token,
      };
      console.log(mData);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: "/Achievement",
        data: mData,
        success: function(e) {
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }


      });
    });
    });
```

is there anything i miss, thanks before, sorry for bad english

Comment: a 500 server error can be basically anything related to the server. You need to find your actual server logs to find out the actual error.

Comment: For Laravel, you can also check in `server/logs` for information